# Replace NA in one row of data frame with values from other

Tags: r, replace, row, na

i want to replace NA in one row with values from another row, example data are:

```
group <-c('A','A_old')
year1<- c(NA,'20')
year2<- c(NA,'40')
year3<- c('20','230')
datac=data_frame(group,year1,year2,year3)
```

[image]

```
group <-c('A','A_old')
year1<- c('20','20')
year2<- c('40','40')
year3<- c('20','230')
finaldatac=data_frame(group,year1,year2,year3)
```

[image]

Original table is much larger so referring to each element one by one and assigning value is not possible..

Thanks!

For sake of argument below, i need to refer to the row values by their name as original table is big and i can not play around with only two rows. For example in table below, i would like to replace row 1 (group==A) with row 5 (group==E). Data are here:

```
group <-c('A','B','C','D','E','F','G')
year1<- c(NA,'100',NA,'200','300',NA,NA)
year2<- c(NA,'100',NA,'200','300','50','40')
year3<- c('20','100',10,'200','300','150','230')
data=data.frame(group,year1,year2,year3)
```

SO i want to get:

```
group <-c('A','B','C','D','E','F','G')
year1<- c('300','100',NA,'200','300',NA,NA)
year2<- c('300','100',NA,'200','300','50','40')
year3<- c('20','100',10,'200','300','150','230')
data=data.frame(group,year1,year2,year3)
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you need `datac %>% fill(!!! rlang::syms(names(.)), .direction = 'up')`

Comment: Or you can try `datac %>%
 fill(everything(), .direction = "up")`.

Comment: thanks for suggestions, unfortunately my original data are much larger so it will have more than just two groups (rows) and in many cases they are not next to each other.. can i refer somehow to the rows i want to replace directly by group value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than using `fill` or `na.locf`, you could do:

```
datac %>%
  group_by(grp = gsub("_.*", "", group)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(contains("year")),
                 funs(.[!is.na(.)])) %>%
  ungroup() %>% select(-grp)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  group year1 year2 year3
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     20    40    20   
2 A_old 20    40    230
```

For your second example, you could do:

```
data %>%
  mutate_at(
    vars(contains("year")), 
    funs(
      case_when(
        group == "A" & is.na(.) ~ .[group == "E"],
        TRUE ~ .)
      )
    )
```

Output:

```
  group year1 year2 year3
1     A   300   300    20
2     B   100   100   100
3     C  <NA>  <NA>    10
4     D   200   200   200
5     E   300   300   300
6     F  <NA>    50   150
7     G  <NA>    40   230
```

You can also add other conditions to `case_when`.

For instance, if you'd additionally like to replace `C` years with what is there for group `D`, you would add:

```
data %>%
  mutate_at(
    vars(contains("year")), 
    funs(
      case_when(
        group == "A" & is.na(.) ~ .[group == "E"],
        group == "C" & is.na(.) ~ .[group == "D"],
        TRUE ~ .)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but in case i have big data and only few rows i want to modify how i would i refer to exact rows with which i want to values?

Comment: Hm, hard to judge - I think in this case you would need to provide us with a larger example of your dataframe, both input and final output.

Comment: Thanks! Can this be modified so that A take value of E only when A==NA?, so it would be 300,300,20...

Comment: Of course - see the modified code. Basically you can manipulate this with various different conditions just like in normal `ifelse` statements.

Answer (score 0):

After a very long evening and headache from r i managed to get this:

```
rm(list = ls())
group <-c('A','A old')
year1<- c(NA,'20')
year2<- c(NA,'40')
year3<- c('20','230')
datac=data_frame(group,year1,year2,year3)
group <-c('A','A old')
year1<- c('20','20')
year2<- c('40','40')
year3<- c('20','230')
finaldatac=data_frame(group,year1,year2,year3)


datac$group <- gsub(' ', '--', datac$group)
datact = t(datac)
colnames(datact) = datact[1, ] 
datact = datact[-1, ] 

datact[,"A"]  <- ifelse(!is.na(datact[,"A"]), datact[,"A"] , datact[,"A--old"])
datactt=t(datact)
group = rownames(datactt)
datactt<-cbind(datactt, group)
rownames(datactt) <- c()
datactt <- as.data.frame(datactt)

sapply(datactt, class)
datactt <- data.frame(lapply(datactt, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


datactt$group <- gsub('--', ' ', datactt$group)
```

Where datactt (hopefully) is the same as finaldatac that i wanted... I am sure this cant be the best solution, obviously not the prettiest. If anybody has something similar, but shorter or more efficient please post it i would appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple replacement in `Base R` can be done with:

```
data[1,is.na(data[1,])] <- data[5,is.na(data[1,])]
```

Taking in account that only need to know row indices of desired replacements.